# MPAndroidChart - How to customize the markerview text?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

How I can customize the text of the `MarkerView`?

I want that when pressing on a bar, the markerview is displayed, and the text of the MarkerView display a text that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the [documentation of the markerview](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/MarkerView).

There you can find information how to achieve what you want.
Basically, you will have to extend the `MarkerView` class and refresh it's content in the `refreshContent(Entry e, int dataSetIndex)` method.